# Application of expected value in normal distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let X be the diameter of a semi-precious rock. Consider $X \sim N(10,1)$, the value of the rock is given by

| X<8 | |X-10|<2 | X>12 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 20 |

How can I calculate the expected value of the rock?

My attempt:

The expected value of the rock should be something like $$1\cdot \mathbb{P}(X<8) + 10\cdot \mathbb{P}(8<X<12)+20\cdot \mathbb{P}(X>12)$$

If that's correct, I get
$$1\cdot 0.0228+10\cdot 0.9545+ 20 \cdot 0.0228 = 10.0238$$

But honestly, I don't have a clue if that make any sense. Any hit is appreciated!!

Comment: Your method makes sense, though your final answer has tiny  rounding issues: it is in fact closer to $1\cdot 0.02275+10\cdot 0.954500+ 20 \cdot 0.022750 = 10.02275$.  If you had said $\approx 10.02$ then it would have been fine

Comment: "widget" is a good generic term for a physical object, often in the context of manufacturing or economics.

Comment: Your solution makes sense to me. Writing $h$ for the function you describe in the table, the expectation is computed as always by the integral $E[h(X)]=\int h(x) \phi(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ where $\phi$ is the density function for $X.$ That integral is best evaluated in three parts and, because $h$ has a constant value on each part, it appears your formula corresponds to them.